# Back button inside ion-nav-buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm able to create a functioning back button by following the documentation http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBackButton/

```
<ion-nav-bar ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon">
    <i class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></i>{{getPreviousTitle() || 'Back'}}
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicNavBarDelegate) {
  $scope.getPreviousTitle = function() {
    return $ionicNavBarDelegate.getPreviousTitle();
  };
}
```

`<ion-nav-back-button>` doesn't work for me for some reason.

I'd like to only show the back button in certain states. If I put a generic button inside ionic-nav-buttons it works. Putting a back button doesn't.

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">

</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Is there any way to put a back button inside ion-nav-buttons? I tried `<ion-nav-back-button>` but it doesn't work either way.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Only manually adding back buttons. Which, in this application makes sense as the specs require the text to change.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it by using the following:

```
<ion-view title="Dashboard" hide-back-button="true">
  <ion-content">
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I hope this helps.